Copy text with color highlighting from Visual Studio
How can I copy (and paste) text from Visual Studio maintaining the colors?
If I copy from VS Code, the colors are preserved (e.g. for C# Code). But copying from Visual Studio, only the "typewriter" font (Cascadia Mono) information is copied.

Version: Visual Studio 2022 - (17.9.7)

I checked the option "Copy rich text on copy/cut". I even unchecked it, restarted, checked it and started again - with no effects.
Is this a bug? Or did I miss something?


pasting to Outlook it used to do it in rich text by default. But now I have to choose Keep format.

It might be a bug according to the documentation, which states

Selected by default, the option copies text that includes colors and ligatures.

and (not shown in your screenshot, but on that same dialog),

Use accurate classification
Toggle this checkbox to allow for semantic colorization. A "wait" dialog might appear after a few seconds. (There's syntactic colorization, which is fast to copy, and semantic colorization, which is slower to copy. Semantic information allows for richer and more accurate colorization.)

Try turning both of these on. Also,

if you're copying more than the threshold number of characters, those over the threshold lose their markup
ensure the source you're copying to actually has the ability to support rich text (Word for example should accept rich text)

If none of that works, you might be out of luck and should submit a Developer Community suggestion.
It's worth including Peter's comment in this answer. Thank you Peter.

It's a bug in the recent VS versions, indeed. Even the Copy As Html 2022 extension from Microsoft suffers from this problem. According to the discussion on their site, it's caused by the recent Roslyn breaking change. We need to wait.


It's a bug in the recent VS versions, indeed. Even the Copy As Html 2022 extension from Microsoft suffers from this problem. According to the discussion on their site, it's caused by the recent Roslyn breaking change. We need to wait.
